# How to add same security group rule from both requester and accepter VPCs in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have two terraform structures, and there is VPC peering between them. Requester VPC should reach some of the applications in Accepter. I created VPC peering in requester's terraform, gave accepter's Route Tables to requester's `variables.tf` as variables and it's created and functioning properly. When I ran `terraform plan` in accepter terraform, it was simply trying to delete the routes that I added via requester terraform. To prevent this, I added same routes to accepter route tables in accepter terraform and it's showing no change and everything is fine.

Here is my problem,

I'm trying to do same process for security groups. As I said, some apps should reach from requester to accepter. Since requester is demanding VPC peering, I decided to security group rules in requester terraform for accepter security groups. I added them, after that I ran `terraform plan` for accepter structure. It's trying to delete stranger rules that was applied via VPC peered structure, this is expected, okay. So I added same rules to accepter terraform to avoid changes. and I ran it. But rather than avoiding the changes as it does in route tables,

It's giving the error below.
`Error: InvalidPermission.Duplicate: the specified rule "peer: sg-xx, TCP, from port: xx, to port: xx, ALLOW" already exists status code: 400,`
I want to keep these rules defined in both sides because it makes things more clear. Since I have different security groups for different resource types in my structures, these security groups are sort of representing the resource. I want to be able to define these rules to both sides to understand which resource is needed for which VPC-peered component. How can I ignore the error above and make my system work this way?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you at least add some Terraform code? It's hard to understand what might be wrong.

Comment: Hi, I think there is no problem with the Terraform code, as I said it's working. I wanted to know is adding same security group rule from two different terraform structures like it's been working for aws_route. lets say I have a VPN structure, and also prod structure. These are completely separated Terraform structures file-wise. But to make them communicate, there is VPC peering between them. And vpc peering configs were defined for prod route table from VPN terraform. lets say there is prod public and prod private route tables, VPC peering configs added these route tables from VPN terraform.

Comment: Because I'm creating VPC peering from VPN terraform. When I first ran the prod Terraform, it's trying to remove peering configs from prod public and private route tables. This behaviour is expected. There is no problem. To solve it, I added same peering configs to prod terraform, When I ran terraform plan in prod side, it's not trying to remove peering configs anymore and showing no change. I was trying to do completely same process with security groups. I added security group rule lets say prod mysql security group for VPN permission from VPN terraform. Again, I ran plan prod structure

Comment: It's again trying to remove VPN rule from prod mysql security group. To prevent it, I modify the security group from prod side too, I added VPN permissions for prod mysql from prod structure. But it's behaving differently. Rather than showing no change like it did in route tables, it's giving the error above. I want to know why it's behaving like this. What's different between route table configs and sg rules. I know it's complicated but as I said it's not related with the my Terraform files, this is more like a methodological question.